# Exclude a value from AVG in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have a table where i have to find the avg price of an item, the problem is that i have to exclude a payment option from the avg

lets say the table goes like this
Example

[image]

I want to remove cash payments from this avg

Comment: So, why not use that condition in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `WHERE` statement to filter out cash payments.

```
SELECT AVG(total)
FROM yourtable
WHERE payment != 'cash'
```